# How do I go back and edit data in a node in a linked list when my data has multiple elements?

Tags: c#, c

This is how my linked list is set up. Essentially I am reading in data of a customer and the restaurant they visited. Data is in random order, but when I come across the same customer I need to go back and edit the node that was created for them and add values to timesVisited. How do I do this and should I change the setup of my linked list? I am not using files.

```
typedef struct customers {
    char customerId[CUSTOMER_ID_LENGTH];
    int timesVisited[MAX_RESTAURANT_REC];
    
} data_t;


typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    data_t *data;
    node_t *next;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *foot;
} list_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the new entry, customerId already exists in the list, one by one on each node, you can use the string compare function, down below short working example, but first let me explain some code snips:

In `typedef struct customer` the pointer to the structure shouldn't be nested, declare it inside the struct.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CUSTOMER_ID_LENGTH 80

char clients_id[][CUSTOMER_ID_LENGTH] =
{
    "AA01",
    "AA02",
};


typedef struct customer
{
    char customerId[CUSTOMER_ID_LENGTH];
    int timesVisited;
    struct customer *next; // you should avoid nested structs
}customer_t;
```

List function typically goes from head to tail, your code should ever remember the head and recognize the tail because of a `NULL` pointer.

```c
void print_customers(customer_t *head)
{
  customer_t * current = head;

  while (current != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", current->customerId);
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

The following code doesn't use a loop, it has just two nodes, but quickly you can get the idea.

```c
int main()
{
    customer_t *head =  NULL;

    head = (customer_t *) malloc(sizeof(customer_t));
    strcpy(head->customerId, clients_id[0]);
    head->timesVisited = 1;
    head->next = NULL;

    head->next = (customer_t *) malloc(sizeof(customer_t));
    strcpy(head->next->customerId, clients_id[1]);
    head->timesVisited = 1;
    head->next->next = NULL;

    print_customers(head);

    // Change customer entry string and see what happens
    char customer_entry[CUSTOMER_ID_LENGTH] = "AA02";

    if((strcmp(head->customerId, customer_entry) == 0)|| (strcmp(head->next->customerId, customer_entry) == 0))
    {
        printf("\nCustomer alredy in list");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nCustomer is not in the list, just add");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[run code online](https://tio.run/##pVPvb9MwEP3uv@LIhBRPHUv5NKlk0lQmmFSGBBtftioK9rUxSp3IdoHC@rd3duL8aBuEEPmQOO/u3nuX3LGzJWO73YmQLF9zhDfacFG8yi7JHpSLr4eYEnLpMHLCcSEkwvT@893HD9efkpu3yez69t3de7iICGFZqoDlAqXRieAP84fjxDnE5DcBewVXV9E4GLXn1/a8nRBCzKZEKwRWeM0MsLU2xQqVL6tFPHbDhyQmVaKQBoxYof4itDDIa/SAFE4l/jQTsm2AxL6Q74XgUNq2TdLgOuwy4DTDlFPwhnq4fVHKtg8xuBRL5TJ@ZCJHCJvYixhu72ezpt5dldYiDF7qRxmMGpazy65POmmTO402r27CBbdkS4hrfZUKGVJy7NEZs7WVB2/QQ3stUsuQ5wULtfiFxaIXo7T9lKzchK6473TUH4Fo7pPrrP7/sILjfsz1APGhrRb/H3OO4o8Wx/9mccjo4ahU4@Fj5@cwzVK5xG7mrLLaQL1XkEoOGtEOSWogS8sSpT4e9KSqGd4nvz1eTyzC0DW/Kof@zB4dhTiGiD49wX7FwOcaqqOV3vEQP8pp02maK@Qbu4qQC20C2syou2Ou8e8MQoMsjGMwGVYsI/hmg5By3vFVD4VmrSREdpvJbvcM)

Comment: please add the essence of your idea in the actual answer as code snippet.

Comment: Falco, did you mean I should improve the answer by adding some code? online code is not enough?

Comment: online code is a nice add on, but what if the external site is down/deprecated?